# Print in mutilple pages in UWP?

Tags: uwp

I have requirement to print the "Page" in UWP.

The problem i am facing is, "TextBlock" contain large amount of data because of which content in "Print Preview" as well as "Printed" page is getting cut off.

Please help how i can handle this issue.

Thanks,
Prasoon

Comment: Did you actually check the provided example by Microsoft? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing